# "Выполнить" — оттенок значения, контексты употребления

Tags: семантика

Можете объяснить, чем отличается слово "выполнить" от своих синонимов ("произвести", "осуществить" и т. п.)? Какое имеет отличное семантическое значение, индивидуальный оттенок смысла, в каких случаях применяется?

Насколько я понимаю, возможны такие сочетания.

Выполнить разворот, поворот, движение, комплекс, действие (к процессу). Я предполагаю, что подобные сочетания употребляются в описании работ ЭВМ или разл. спортивных упражнений.

Comment: Но ведь именно это объясняет *Толковый словарь русского языка*. Ожегов, если не путаю с Ушаковым, доступен онлайн. Неужели кто-то сможет объяснить лучше?

Comment: Нет, там приведено два значения. "Создать" и "Выполнить задуманное". Во второе из них может большое количество случаев как вписаться, так и не вписаться.